# How to get the absolute screen coordinates of an element placed inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinates

I have a ListView that uses a UserControl as DataTemplate:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:TaskerInfoView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I need the absolute screen coordinates of a Button placed inside the TaskerInfoView usercontrol.

I tried with this code:

```
var newButtonPoint = button.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
```

but I received the exception "This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource" I suppose because the button is inside a DataTemplate so it's not connected to a visual element.

UPDATE
I've found why I had received that exception: before the `PointToScreen` call I move the item inside the ObersvableCollection, that is the ItemsSource of the ListView:

```
this._taskList.Move(currentIndex, currentIndex - 1);  // _taskList is the ObservableCollection<>
var newButtonPoint = button.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
```

If I remove the `ObservableCollection<>.Move`, the PointToScreen works correctly.

I think that internally the `ObservableCollection<>.Move` removes the item and inserts another one in the new position. The exception is raised because `button` contains a reference to the removed element that is actually disconnected from the TreeVisual

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.indexfromcontainer.aspx

Comment: I now see that you are using a listview i thought that was a listbox 
but it's suppose  to be the same.

Comment: Where are you using that code? I tried it in a test event handler for the `UserControl` and everything seemed to work.

Comment: Glad you've figured out the root cause =D

Answer (score 1):

For example :

xaml :

```
    <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" SelectedIndex="2">
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>5</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <Button Content="GetIndexFromContainer" Click="Button_Click" />
```

cs :

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var index = GetSelectedIndexFromList();
    }

    private int GetSelectedIndexFromList()
    {
        var container = myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MyListBox.SelectedItem);
        var index = myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container);
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't need the relative position of the item inside the list. I updated/improved the question ;)